# Playframework PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Unique index or primary key violation

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework

I'm making a little "website" using the playframework. I've made a method to create a ploeg en to display them. but when I try to delete them (made a button to do that) ik gives me this error:

```
    [PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Unique index or primary key
    violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_4 ON PUBLIC.PLOEG(ID)"; SQL statement:\n insert into ploeg 
    (id, naam, punten) values (?,?,?) [23505-172]]]
```

This is the method in my Ploeg.java where the mistake is situated:

```
    public static void maak(Ploeg ploeg) {
        ploeg.save();
    }
```

This is my Ploeg.java:

```
package models;

import play.data.validation.Constraints;
import play.db.ebean.Model;

import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;
/**
 * Created by Bram on 3/01/14.
 */

@Entity
public class Ploeg extends Model {

@Id
public Long id;

//@Required
public String naam;
public Integer punten;

public static Finder<Long, Ploeg> find = new Finder(
        Long.class, Ploeg.class
);

public static List<Ploeg> all() {
    return find.all();
}

public static Ploeg maak(Ploeg ploeg) {
    ploeg.save();
    return ploeg;
}

public static void delete(Long id) {
    find.ref(id).delete();
}

public static void geefPunt(Long id) {
    Ploeg ploegje = find.byId(id);
    ploegje.punten = ploegje.punten + 3;
}
```

}

Now that method is called from my Applicaion.java like this:

```
    public static Result deletePloeg(Long id) {
        Ploeg.delete(id);
        return redirect(routes.Application.ploegen());
    }
```

And again that method is trigger from index.scala.html by clicking the delete button:

```
    @form(routes.Application.deletePloeg(ploeg.id)) {
        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
    }
```

I hope someone can help me explain what this error means and how to solve it. I've been trying to do so for over 6 hours now.

Comment: Check why insert statement is executing on deletion

Comment: I did that, but I can't find where it calls up that insert statement. You can see which steps it runs through, and no sign where it triggers the insert function or any other function.

Comment: the error is simply saying in db there is a row with same primary key so primary key should be unique .Also Post your `Ploeg` class

Comment: what `routes.Application.ploegen()` this method doing.I think this is generating a new Plogen and generating insert statement .Also make the id auto generate `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`

Comment: That routes.Application.ploegen() is a rerout to the page where all the ploegen are displayed. This it what is does: `return ok(views.html.index.render(Ploeg.all(), ploegForm));`

Comment: I tried that `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` , but that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my routes file I hade this line:

```
POST    /ploegen                    controllers.Application.deletePloeg(id: Long)
```

And I changed it to:

```
POST    /                           controllers.Application.deletePloeg(id: Long)
```

I don't know why, but it works!